# getting highlighted text coordinates from another application

Tags: windows, winapi

Is there any way to get coordinates of a rectangle used to highlight text (such as when you select a piece of text for example with mouse for further copying to clipboard) from a third party application?

I guess it won't be possible when application does some custom rendering, but what about standard controls? There seems to be some central way for drawing the highlighting rectangle, but I couldn't find any useful information about this. Also clipboard interception doesn't seem to return such info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [EM_GETSEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761598%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the selection range in characters, then [EM_POSFROMCHAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761631%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the coordinates of each character as displayed in the edit control's client area.